# Change the column entries, based on certain condition, for every group/id, in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the below dataframe:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd

#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
               4, 4, 4, 4,
               5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5,5],
        'cycle': [1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                  1,2, 3,4,5,6,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,
                  1,2, 3, 4,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   4, 4, 4,4,5,6,
                   8,9,10,11,12,13,
                   8,9,10,11,
                   7, 7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,],
        'Children': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes',
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes',
                      'No',  'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141,
                 141,123, 128, 66,
                 123, 128, 66, 123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataframe looks as such:

[image]

Here, every id has different cycles as per the 'cycle' column. For example,

id-1 has maximum 11 cycles.

id-2 has maximum 6 cycles.

id-3 has maximum 6 cycles.

id-4 has maximum 4 cycles.

id-5 has maximum 9 cycles.

I have a certain threshold limit on 'cycles'. Let's say cycle_threshold = 8

If maximum cycles for and id < cycle_threshold, then 'Days' column remain unchanged.
Else,'Days' column will be marked as 'NA'.

For example,

For id-2, since maximum cycles are 6, which is < 8, the 'Days' column remains unchanged

However, for id-1, since maximum cycles are 11, which is > 8, the 'Days' column becomes 'NA'.

The result looks as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how do I achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for get maximal `cycle` per groups, compare by `cycle_threshold` and set `NaN`s in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
cycle_threshold = 8

m1 = df.groupby('id')['cycle'].transform('max').lt(cycle_threshold)
df['Days'] = df['Days'].where(m1)

#alternative
df.loc[~m1, 'Days'] = np.nan
```

---

```
print("df = \n", df)
     id  cycle  Salary Children   Days
0    1      1       7       No    NaN
1    1      2       7      Yes    NaN
2    1      3       7      Yes    NaN
3    1      4       8      Yes    NaN
4    1      5       9      Yes    NaN
5    1      6      10       No    NaN
6    1      7      11       No    NaN
7    1      8      12      Yes    NaN
8    1      9      13      Yes    NaN
9    1     10      14      Yes    NaN
10   1     12      15       No    NaN
11   2      1       4      Yes   96.0
12   2      2       4      Yes  120.0
13   2      3       4       No  120.0
14   2      4       4      Yes  141.0
15   2      5       5      Yes   52.0
16   2      6       6      Yes   96.0
17   3      1       8       No   15.0
18   3      2       9      Yes  123.0
19   3      3      10      Yes  128.0
20   3      4      11       No   66.0
21   3      5      12       No  120.0
22   3      6      13      Yes  141.0
23   4      1       8      Yes  141.0
24   4      2       9       No  123.0
25   4      3      10      Yes  128.0
26   4      4      11      Yes   66.0
27   5      1       7       No    NaN
28   5      2       7      Yes    NaN
29   5      3       9       No    NaN
30   5      4      10       No    NaN
31   5      5      11      Yes    NaN
32   5      6      12      Yes    NaN
33   5      7      13      Yes    NaN
34   5      8      14      Yes    NaN
35   5      9      15       No    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can get the max of `cycle` per `id` column and check if it is greater than 8. If it is, mask the whole group as NaN

```py
df['Days'] = df['Days'].mask(df.groupby('id')['cycle'].transform('max').gt(8))
```

```
print(df)

    id  cycle  Salary Children   Days
0    1      1       7       No    NaN
1    1      2       7      Yes    NaN
2    1      3       7      Yes    NaN
3    1      4       8      Yes    NaN
4    1      5       9      Yes    NaN
5    1      6      10       No    NaN
6    1      7      11       No    NaN
7    1      8      12      Yes    NaN
8    1      9      13      Yes    NaN
9    1     10      14      Yes    NaN
10   1     11      15       No    NaN
11   2      1       4      Yes   96.0
12   2      2       4      Yes  120.0
13   2      3       4       No  120.0
14   2      4       4      Yes  141.0
15   2      5       5      Yes   52.0
16   2      6       6      Yes   96.0
17   3      1       8       No   15.0
18   3      2       9      Yes  123.0
19   3      3      10      Yes  128.0
20   3      4      11       No   66.0
21   3      5      12       No  120.0
22   3      6      13      Yes  141.0
23   4      1       8      Yes  141.0
24   4      2       9       No  123.0
25   4      3      10      Yes  128.0
26   4      4      11      Yes   66.0
27   5      1       7       No    NaN
28   5      2       7      Yes    NaN
29   5      3       9       No    NaN
30   5      4      10       No    NaN
31   5      5      11      Yes    NaN
32   5      6      12      Yes    NaN
33   5      7      13      Yes    NaN
34   5      8      14      Yes    NaN
35   5      9      15       No    NaN
```

Comment: You can use: `df.groupby('id').transform('size').gt(8)` if you consider cycle is continuous.

Comment: @Corralien Not quitely, I test that `groupby.transform('size')` should specify a column, such as `df.groupby('id')['cycle'].transform('size')`

Comment: You don't need to test a particular column, you just test the size of the group: `df['Days'].mask(df.groupby('id').transform('size').gt(8))`

Comment: @Corralien - Depends of pandas version, on last one not necessary. I also prefer working solution in oldies pandas

Comment: @Corralien `df.groupby('id').transform('size')` gives a `TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types` error on my v1.4.3 and I can't figure out which column is invalid for `size` function.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh. OK, I get it, I used Pandas=1.5.3 so it works.